# Testing ListPreference

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I'm trying to test android preferences, and I'm a bit confused as to how to achieve that result.

Here is my preference

```
<PreferenceScreen 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ListPreference
    android:id="@+id/numberListPreference"
    android:defaultValue="3"
    android:entries="@array/number_text"
    android:entryValues="@array/number_value"
    android:key="@string/pref_key"
    android:summary="@string/pref_summary"
    android:title="@string/pref_title" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I want to test that when I change the number in the displayed ListPreference, the SharedPreference is actually changed.

Right now, the code works, I'm just blocking on the testing part.

Here is part of my activity :

```
public class SettingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I have the classic "If the target view is not part of the view hierarchy" error.

Any help is welcomed.
Thx !

Answer (score 6):

```
@Test
    public void clickListPreference() throws Exception{

        // Check if it is displayed
        Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

        onData(allOf(
           is(instanceOf(Preference.class)),
           withKey(appContext.getResources().getString(R.string.pref_key))))
          .check(matches(isDisplayed()));

        // Check if click is working
        onData(allOf(
           is(instanceOf(Preference.class)),
           withKey(appContext.getResources().getString(R.string.pref_key))))           
          .onChildView(withText(appContext.getResources()
              .getString(R.string.pref_title))).perform(click());
 }
```

Hope this will help you... Put your shared preference under click action